# Node + React - Hyphenated CSS Class Names

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, sass, babeljs

I'm currently using `react-starter-kit` and have a few react components each with their own styling file (scss). Basically, every component imports styling file on top like:

```
import s from './Header.scss';
```

Now, for css classes that do not have hyphens (e.g: 'notification'), I can use it without any problem, but I can't figure out how to use hyphenated css classes:

```
render() {
 return (
  <div className={s.header-inner}> </div>
 );
}
```

This obviously throws an error: 'inner is undefined'.

I changed `header-inner` to `header_inner` and the same in my component and it works fine but I can't do it as my css file is pretty huge with hundreds of classes.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`-` isn't a valid identifier character, so your original code would be evaluated as:

```
s.header - inner
```

You haven't defined a variable called `inner` so you get a reference error.

However any character can be used to make up a key for an object, so you can use a string to access the property you want.

```
return (
  <div className={s['header-inner']}> </div>
);
```

Answer (score 15):

You can set css class by dot without using a string inside a bracket.

See https://github.com/webpack/css-loader

If you set webpack config's css-loader to

```
css-loader?camelCase
```

Now you can do something like this

```
<div className={s.headerInner}> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s['header-inner']
```

In Javascript, dot notation is a convenience, but it doesn't work for illegal variables. In that case, use the bracket notation.

Also, unrelated but you'll likely encounter this soon as well: CSS styles in javascript are turned camelCase. So, if you're setting a style:

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFF', zIndex: 3 }} />
```

Comment: Yep, got it. Thanks!