# next js getting Unhandled Runtime Error for css tag

Tags: javascript, next.js

I getting error for this line of css code:

```
 <div className={`${style.about__me-image}`}> .
```

how to properly add nextjs css for above line  ?

getting this error
`Server Error ReferenceError: image is not defined`

see the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: You'll have to use ``className={`${style['about__me-image']}`}`` instead. See [Node + React - Hyphenated CSS Class Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827356/node-react-hyphenated-css-class-names).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the dash "-" between about__me and Image since it is inside `${}`